# Laravel Vuejs Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am new to vuejs, I am developing a new laravel-vuejs project. When I run **npm run dev**, it gives this error Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'. I am running the application using http://127.0.0.1:8000/

index.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{{ env('APP_NAME') }}</title>
    <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: The cause for that error would probably be in your resources/js/app.js file

Comment: when i run "npm run hot" the error disappear, but do not know why this error is still when run "npm run dev"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was running **npm run dev** and **npm run watch** and there was no error on compilation but when i was running the application using the **http://127.0.0.1:8000/**.

I was getting an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
```

I kept googling to find the solution for it, then I came to know that I have to run:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public/
```

and then run the following:

```
http://localhost:8000/
```

Cheers!